# Script namespace support in Mule ESB

Tags: esb, mule

Which jar do I have to add in build path for the scripting schema, as I am getting the error below:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cos-ct-extends.1.4.3.2.2.1.b:
The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. 
Type 'scriptType' is mixed, but its base type is not
```

while using this namespace declaration:

```
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.1/mule-scripting.xsd"
```

Comment: What exact Mule version are you using? Are you deploying on Mule standalone or embedded?

Comment: Yes, the version matters. i changed the script to "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.2/mule-scripting.xsd".Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a namespace declaration declaration that is consistent with your Mule version.